# Spider Solitaire code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Hi If I want check or see the code in C# for the spider solitaire game where should I go ?

I want to know how the game work and how the code is organized , any Idea ? or link ? or e-books?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 6):

Spider is a port of a game called `KPatience`. It is included in the KDE games distribution for linux. Being GPL, the source code should be easy to obtain. You'll have to port it to C# yourself.

http://games.kde.org/get.php

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at **CodeProject**:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/Cards_Game_Library.aspx

This is a C# class library for card games.

Answer (score 2):

Is spider solitaire an open source program?  Most programs are closed-source, which means that the source code is not available legally.

If you aren't looking for any particular version, check around sourceforge: it's a very good resource for many different open-source projects.

Answer (score 2):

There are also the Little Projects and whatnot that Microsoft offers for VS. They have solitaire and a few other games. That would be a great place to start looking. The Starter Kits for C# Can be found At [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/express/aa700775.aspx).